# How do I load an IStream into a TMemoryStream

Tags: delphi, activex, delphi-xe2, c++builder

How do I use a TComInterface<IStream> object and read it into a TMemoryStream? Can I take  TComInterface<IStream> and use it as a TStream* somehow to use the TMemoryStream LoadFromStream call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to `Read()` the `IStream` data into a buffer that you then `Write()` to the `TMemoryStream`, eg:

```cpp
TComInterface<IStream> pIStrm;
TMemoryStream *pMStrm;

...

STATSTG stat = {0};
OleCheck(pIStrm->Stat(&stat, STATFLAG_NONAME));

LARGE_INTEGER li;
li.QuadPart = 0;
ULARGE_INTEGER ul;
OleCheck(pIStrm->Seek(li, STREAM_SEEK_CUR, &ul));
unsigned __int64 ulPos = ul.QuadPart;

BYTE buffer[1024];
while (ulPos < stat.cbSize.QuadPart)
{
    ULONG ulRead;
    OleCheck(pIStrm->Read(buffer, min(stat.cbSize.QuadPart - ulPos, sizeof(buffer)), &ulRead));
    pMStrm->WriteBuffer(buffer, ulRead);
    ulPos += ulRead;
}

...
```

Another option is to write a `TStream`-derived class that accesses the `IStream` internally (similar to how the RTL's `TStreamAdapter` class wraps a `TStream` so it can be passed around as an `IStream`), eg:

```cpp
class TIStreamWrapper : public TStream
{
private:
    TComInterface<IStream> pIStrm;

protected:
    virtual __int64 __fastcall GetSize();
    virtual void __fastcall SetSize(const __int64 NewSize);

public:
    __fastcall TIStreamWrapper(IStream *Strm);
    virtual int __fastcall Read(void *Buffer, int Count);
    virtual int __fastcall Write(const void *Buffer, int Count);
    virtual __int64 __fastcall Seek(const __int64 Offset, TSeekOrigin Origin);
};

__fastcall TIStreamWrapper::TIStreamWrapper(IStream *Strm)
    : pIStrm(Strm, true)
{
}

__int64 __fastcall TIStreamWrapper::GetSize()
{
    STATSTG stat = {0};
    OleCheck(pIStrm->Stat(&stat, STATFLAG_NONAME));
    return stat.cbSize.QuadPart;
}

void __fastcall TIStreamWrapper::SetSize(const __int64 NewSize)
{
    ULARGE_INTEGER ul;
    ul.QuadPart = NewSize;
    OleCheck(pIStrm->SetSize(ul));
}

int __fastcall TIStreamWrapper::Read(void *Buffer, int Count)
{
    ULONG ulRead;
    OleCheck(pIStrm->Read(Buffer, Count, &ulRead));
    return ulRead;
}

int __fastcall TIStreamWrapper::Write(const void *Buffer, int Count)
{
    ULONG ulWritten;
    OleCheck(pIStrm->Write(Buffer, Count, &ulWritten));
    return ulWritten;
}

static const DWORD IStreamSeekOrigin[] = {STREAM_SEEK_SET, STREAM_SEEK_CUR, STREAM_SEEK_END};

__int64 __fastcall TIStreamWrapper::Seek(const __int64 Offset, TSeekOrigin Origin)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    li.QuadPart = Offset;
    ULARGE_INTEGER ul;
    OleCheck(pIStrm->Seek(li, IStreamSeekOrigin[Origin], &ul));
    return ul.QuadPart;
}
```

```cpp
TComInterface<IStream> pIStrm;
TMemoryStream *pMStrm;
...
TIStreamWrapper *pWrapper = new TIStreamWrapper(pIStrm);
try
{
    pMStrm->LoadFromStream(pWrapper);
    // or: pMStrm->CopyFrom(pWrapper, 0);
}
__finally
{
    delete pWrapper;
}

...
```

Comment: Remy, I know this is an older post but doesn't this [blog](http://chrisbensen.blogspot.com/2009/01/working-with-istream-in-delphi.html) from Chris Benson help with this?

Comment: I was probably not aware of `TOleStream` at the time I wrote this answer. Looking at `TOleStream` now, I notice that it does not support 64-bit streams. This code does. Other than that, this code is almost identical to the code that `TOleStream` uses, with the only exceptions being that this code's implementation of the `Size` property getter is more optimized than `TOleStream`'s implementation is, and this code implements the `Size` property setter whereas `TOleStream` does not.

Comment: Ok. I didn't notice the issue with 64-bit streams. Thanks for the heads up.